# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

i am using the following command and i get a plethora of results

```
 select *
 from sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

i then try to use the following

```
 select SalesOrderID, salesorderdetailid, SUM (OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
 from sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

or

```
 select SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, SUM (OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
 from sales.SalesOrderDetail
 group by SalesOrderDetailID
 having SUM(OrderQty * UnitPrice) > 50
 order by ModifiedDate DESC;
```

and i get an error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Regards 
Panos

Comment: Error message is very clear. Columns in the select list should be either in group by or should be wrapped inside an aggregate

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have columns in the select list that are not in the `group by`.  This is generally not allowed.  Try either:

```
select SalesOrderID, salesorderdetailid, SUM(OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by SalesOrderID, salesorderdetailid
```

or

```
select SalesOrderID, SUM(OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by SalesOrderID
```

or

```
select salesorderdetailid, SUM(OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by salesorderdetailid
```

I don't know which of these, if any, are what you really want, but they do fix the syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have listed two columns  in your SQL SELECT statement that is not encapsulated in the SUM function, you must use the GROUP BY Clause. The SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID fields must, therefore, be listed in the GROUP BY clause.

```
  select SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, SUM (OrderQty * UnitPrice) as price
     from sales.SalesOrderDetail
     group by SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID
     having SUM(OrderQty * UnitPrice) > 50
     order by ModifiedDate DESC;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. It is always better to explain the what, why, and how in your answer.